# Why was David able to see and talk with his dead friend?

Tags: an-american-werewolf-in-london

In "An American Werewolf in London", David is wounded by the werewolf that kills his friend. The werewolf that killed his friend is killed by the locals thereby putting its victims to rest. Davids friend should have been put to rest when his killer died. Why was David able to see and talk to his dead friend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Jack is cursed to exist in a state of living death for as long as the **bloodline** of the werewolf that attacked them survives.

You can read the whole plot [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_American_Werewolf_in_London#Plot). It's not clear how bloodline is interpreted like, but clearly it's not enough for Jack to get the werewolf killed. Probably all the ancestors has to be killed in order to rest in peace.